# I need a GUI that will edit a TEXT column in MySQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, sql

I normally use MySql Workbench.  But I now have a table that has a column of type TEXT.  It is used to store Python script for use in Jython.  Some of these scripts can be quite large.  Workbench only lets me edit as one line.  It really does not work for large TEXT cells.

Any SQL editor that can do this?  Something simple that works like notepad type editor when you select a cell.  Keeping in mind that it is python code, so keeping format (ie new line and tabs, etc.) is essential.

I am using Ubuntu linux  (16.10)

Comment: Rushing to a mereting; I have no time for more than to say  http://www.heidisql.com It's both free & excellent

Answer (score 1):

For your need i think [sqlyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) will be the best product it is although not free but you will get 30 day trial for premium version and support for this.

You can edit text type like this.

[image]

Your text field will retain formatting of your code.

[image]

It has [community version](https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community/wiki/Downloads) too.

**Edit**

I am not sure about sqlyog running on linux environment so you have to use [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) for running this on linux environment.